# Meteor Iron Router: Possible to get rendered html from route

Tags: javascript, meteor, client, url-routing, iron-router

I have a meteor application and am using Iron Router for the routing.

I've got one route called `/process` which is run server side. In the URL parameters i have a parameter named route. What i want to do is for the handler for the route handler to return the HTML that was generated from the route specified in the parameter using this.res.end(- the rendered HTML from the route parameter's route-)

This is bound to be possible but my meteor skills are lacking.

Comment: server-side rendering is not yet supported. You can try some of the workarounds, such as the handlebars-server package, but to the best of my knowledge none of them support full spacebars templates.

Comment: Make sure to vote for [server side rendering in the Meteor roadmap](https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm/7-server-side-rendering).